# Play x265 in ubuntu

Tags: multimedia

I am able to play small size x265 video files in Ubuntu 14 with VLC. But when i am trying to run some heavy file (1 Gb or more), it is lacking and freezing when any fight scene or high graphic scene comes.Is there any solution or alternative for this

Comment: To my knowledge the version of VLC in the repositories of 14.04 doesn't support H.265 video (x265 is an encoder). Please post `mediainfo` output of  the file that gives you problems, your hardware (processor model, amount of ram, display resolution, gpu) and which version of playback software you are using and where you got it from. Your question as it currently is has a terrible overgeneralized title for your actual  problem and isn't reproducible for someone who wants to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using avplay, the basic media player that comes with the libav set of libraries. In the command line interface, run `avplay path/of/your/media/file`.
You can read more about it here https://libav.org/documentation/avplay.html#While-playing.html and in Google, of course.